# closest string/timestamp from a map

Tags: c++

If a timestamp is NOT in a map stored with timestamps I would like to find the closest matching timestamp in the map and use the closest value as a key. I have the basic structure setup for what I'm trying to do i'm just not sure how to find the nearest timestamp

```
typedef std::map<std::string,int>  Map;
Map::iterator it;
Map my_map;

my_map["2010-01-26 17:02:12"]= 1;
my_map["2010-01-25 08:55:29"]= 2;
my_map["2010-01-24 08:55:29"]= 3;

string timestamp = "2010-01-24 08:55:30"; // would return 3
string timestamp1 = "2010-01-27 01:55:30"; // would return 1

  it = my_map.find(timestamp); 
     if(it == my_map.end()){
       //not sure how to approach this
   }
```

**update**

I'm trying to avoid converting a fairly large code base from `std::string` to `uint64_t` although it would increase performance, it's not that big of an issue,

I can't get the `std::map::lower_bound` or `std::map::upper_bound` solutions to work
here is my attempt on IDE ONE,

http://ideone.com/MnRLIH

Comment: First things first -- do not store timestamps as strings. You're just setting yourself up for _a world of hurt_. Once you've fixed that by switching to an integral type, you can experiment with `std::lower_bound`. Don't forget to check the element _above_ the result to see whether it's closer. Take your research in that direction then come back with any problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably get what you need with [`std::map::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) or [`std::map::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound), either of which is *O(log N)* complexity.

---

Also, strongly consider storing your timestamps as, say, a `uint64_t` rather than a string.  This would greatly reduce the amount of computation to compare and process.

Comment: Would DE-referencing of the map's forward iterator evaluate to the value type used when comparing?

Comment: @Abhijit: Ah, good spot.  One needs the `map` versions of these functions.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I understand uint64_t may be more efficient, but i'm trying to avoid that because it would involve a massive rewrite, `std::map::lower_bound` or `std::map::upper_bound` don't really work with `std::string`heres my attempt http://ideone.com/MnRLIH so i guess I have no choice but to rewrite my code?

Comment: @pyCthon: "2" looks like the correct answer to me; the definition of e.g. lower_bound is "the first element that's not less than the input argument".  If you want to find the *closest* element, then you'll need to compare this element and the previous element.  But the hard work was finding this element in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are `upper_bound()` and `lower_bound()` functions, which you can use to find the neighbors above and below.

Comment: both these bsearch functions need to DE-referencing the fwd iterator of the map in order to compare with the key. The Key usually would either be string (in this case or uint64_t as suggested). DE-referencing a fwd iterator I believe should return a pair and would never compare with the value, unless you pass std::pair to upper_bound() but then that needs comparator functions.

Comment: No, I don't think so, though I'm not 100% clear what you mean. Note that there is both a (free) function and a memberfunction in class map. The latter takes a key similar to `find()` (again, the memberfunction, not the free one!).

Comment: Actually, I goofed up still: You only need to call one of them, not both. You can determine the other by simply decrementing the upper bound. You then only need to compare whether that one is equal or not. The challenge there is not dereferencing a past-the-end iterator or decrementing an iterator to the start, but that's business as usual when dealing with STL-style container code.